# Am I supposed to be able to create edges between two edges and/or an edge and a node in OrientDB?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

In OrientDB, I can do `CREATE EDGE E from someEdge to AnotherEdge`. It will execute with no problem, and the edge will be created.

However, if I do this in the graph editor in Studio, it's extremely buggy. The properties/settings window will not work at all.

My question is: is it a bug that it lets me create edges between two edges/an edge and a node or is it 'merely' the graph editor that's buggy when I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation doesn't specifically mention edge to edge relationships: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Relationships.html

A similar question was asked in the OrientDB GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4078

Luca (the CEO of Orient Technologies and a top contributor to OrientDB) suggested that edge to edge relationships are outside of the Property Graph definition and recommends using a vertex of class "subgraph" to get around the problem:

> Edges against edges is out of Property Graph definition. In your domain you could simply create a new vertex of class "subgraph" and connect them using this vertex.

To answer your question specifically, it sounds like edge to edge relationships shouldn't be possible or at least aren't recommended.